# Preventing user from killing an application on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how I can prevent a user from killing an application using force-stop.  I am trying to detect when user opens an activity such as Settings-Applications-Manage Applications and tries to force-stop a protected app.  Also there are some task manager apps that allow you to kill processes.

I know it is possible in Android, since apps like AppLock or Super AppLock do it.  I just can't find any information on how to do it.

Right now I am trying to poll ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo to detect the restricted activities, however that does not work well as they have different names on different devices.

Is there a better way to do it?  How do AppLock and similar apps implement this functionality?

Comment: I thought only system apps were allowed to block that. ie. install with the ROM

Comment: AppLock or Super AppLock, does they work on non-rooted devices? Did you try them? Another possible tip is your app is DeviceAdmin. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: I've tried Super AppLock on my phone (standard non-rooted) and it works fine.  When I try to access Task Manager app or Force-stop the application via Settings/Manage applications I am presented with a screen asking me to enter an unlock code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Using ActivityManager.getRunningTasks() function seems to be the best solution.
Then you just need to pop-up an Activity (with pin code) every time the top task is "com.android.settings.applications.RunningServiceDetails" or "com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails".

Unfortunately, there is no way to see if the user is trying to kill a protected application or some other application, so the access is restricted to all of them.

There are also a bunch of task managers on the market that use ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses() method to kill the process, but you can bring the app back to life by using alarms.

Comment: Does that mean you constantly need to poll using `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()`? Is that a lot of overhead? I'm also very curious how all these App-locking type apps are doing it, esp. since you can't read other apps' LogCat anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[Quite similar and relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477606/disabling-force-stop-button-in-android) was already asked and replied.

Long story in short, **no you cannot** prevent user or the operating system to kill your application off due to memory management.