# Android unstopable Application

Tags: android, permissions

How do make android app. unstoppable from "Application settings" in android phone through program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely not possible for security reasons. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477606/disabling-force-stop-button-in-android) for more information about that.