# Android App and its service is killing automatically within 4 minute

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am working on `Android App` which supports `BLE` devices.

- In some mobile with Android 6. app is  and ble service is killing by OS.
- Is anyone having any idea how to keep running my app in background and after killing the app?

Using `START_STICKY` on service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;}
```

Comment: Could you post any code of your service?

Comment: I am using START_STICKY in my service. updated in question. this is working fine for some mobile phone.

Comment: I researched in internet, i get to know this behaviour is due to doze mode feature in android 6. but I am not sure how to resolve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217819/android-app-needs-not-to-be-wiped-from-memory?noredirect=1#comment69671013_41217819

Comment: i am also trying to solve a pblm similar could you take a look at my quesiton which i have posted above

Answer (score 0):

Start your service in foreground by startForeground(), the in will be no affected by doze mode

Comment: Thanks . But after killing app will it work?? service will run?

Comment: Still your service will be destroyed if someone clears recent apps if you try this.. and it will keep a notification in status bar in always

Comment: This is not working for me.. after killing app all things are clearing (notification, app, service) and service is not restarting even though i am using as START_STICKY.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve a problem similar to your. I think to have a Service always on you must acquire a wakeLock, see here:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: i am releasing wakelock in on task removed callback but some time my service is not restarting automatically when app gets kill. any clue on this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217819/android-app-needs-not-to-be-wiped-from-memory?noredirect=1#comment69671013_41217819    can you take a look at my question and solve it ??? i